# inline date picker in bootstrap3

Tags: html, date, twitter-bootstrap-3, inline

Greeting, I'm unable to align date picker inline the code which I used is below. date picker element goes into a new line rather on the same line.
your help is very much appreciated. thank you.

```js
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap DatePicker</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <p> On this date <input id="datepicker" width="270" /> i accept the offer.</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap DatePicker</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div> On this date <div style="display:inline-block"><input id="datepicker" width="270"  /> </div> i accept the offer.</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```